# windows 10 won't boot after uninstalling GPU

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, gpu

Uninstalled GPU using DDU
Removed the card from the computer

Now windows 10 shows black screen when booting up, startup repair won't work (done that multiple times)
Safemode works, typing this on the computer using safemode

Placed GPU back into computer, changed Bios to boot from PCI.
Windows still doesn't start.

Tried refresh windows option, went all the way up to the screen prior to logging in and then black screen.

Using safe mode done `sfc /scannow` and it didn't find problems.

How can I boot back into my windows without having to reinstall everything?

Update:

Tried changing boot settings using the MSCONFIG and got the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows uses graphics when it can, and if you have a computer that has previously had a graphics card, Windows uses the graphics card's interrupts, instead of the default BIOS interrupts. Try booting in UEFI, if possible. To access the motherboard's BIOS settings, you may need to press a certain button (usually <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, etc.).
If it works in safemode, you may have to re-seat your graphics card. I have had similar issues on a Lenovo desktop.

Comment: Thanks, But the graphics is seated just fine. I can boot into safe mode with it.

Comment: I know how to get into the Bios, I mentioned that I changed the boot graphics mode to PCI. This is not a Bios/Uefi boot problem. Windows boots up untill the point I should get a login screen but shuts down. All hardware the same, no bios changes and I can boot into Safemode. And work for as long as I like. As now I writing this in safemode.

Comment: Problem is something with Windows